# OpenShift Django git push not providing admin username and password - "Everything up-to-date"

Tags: django, git, openshift

I've been trying to set up a django web application using OpenShift, and I've run into a roadblock while following the instructions for setup through git. The instructions state that I should run the following 3 commands:

```
git remote add upstream -m master git://github.com/openshift/django-example.git
git pull -s recursive -X theirs upstream master
git push
```

The first two commands run just fine, but when I run the git push it simply tells me "Everything up-to-date" despite the fact that the instructions state that I should be receiving a block of text that includes my admin username and password.

Since I need the admin un/pw to do any coding, help would very much be appreciated on this matter. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

log to your application with shh

- get your credentiel:

  cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR

  vi CREDENTIALS
- if you want to create new one:

  activate virtenv:

  source $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/python/virtenv/bin/activate

  create new admin account:

  python "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"wsgi/openshift/manage.py createsuperuser

Comment: when i try the first option it shows that CREDENTIALS file is empty and when i follow the second option i get this error message django.db.utils.IntegrityError: auth_user.last_login may not be NULL